# Mysql join mutiple tables to get distinct main table values with pagination and limit

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

1. users

   ```
     Id | first name | last name | email
     1  | john       | pires     | pires@gmail.com
     2  | peter      | robin     | robin@xyz.com
     3  | quinn      | boss      | boss@xyz.com
   ```
2. address

   ```
     Id | user_id | street       | city  | country
     11  | 1       | street-john  | xyz   | usa
     12  | 2       | street-peter | mnp   |  Austrlia
     13  | 3       | street-quinn | mnp   |  Austrlia
   ```

3.contact points.

```
     Id | address_id | type | value
     101 | 11        | phone | 7687676676
     102 | 11        | email | john@yyy.com
     103 | 11        | land phone | 6676
     104 | 12        | website | peter.com
     105 | 12        | website | robin.com
     106 | 12        | website | peter-robin.com
     107 | 12        | website | peter.au
     108 | 13        | website | boss.com
     109 | 13        | website | quinn.com
```

user related to one address and address related to multiple contact points.

I need to fetch users with the related address and their contact points.

So I joined these 3 tables, which results in multiple rows for each user, depending on the number of contact points.

```
    Id | first name |  last name| city | type | value
    1  | john       | pires     | xyz | phone  | 7676767676
    1  | john       | pires     | xyz |email  | john@yyy.com
    1  | john       | pires     | mnp | land phone | 6676
    2  | peter       | robin    | mnp | website | peter.com
    2  | peter       | robin    | mnp | website | robin.com
    2  | peter       | robin    | mnp | website | peter-robin.com
    2 | peter       | robin    | mnp | website | peter.au
    3  | quinn       | boss     | mnp | website | boss.com
    3  | quinn       | boss     | mnp |  website | quinn.com
```

Then I loop through the rows to get each user and store the contact points in an array for each user.

```
<pre>
{ id: 1, firstname: john, city: xyz, contact: [ { type: phone, value: 7676767676 }, { type: email, value: john@yyy}]}
{ id: 2, firstname: peter, city: mnp, contact: [ { type: land phone, value: ... }, { type: .., value: ..}]}
{ id: 3, firstname: quinn, city: mnp, contact: [ { type: website, value: ... }, { type: ..., value: ....}]}
</pre>
```

The problem is when it's paginated.

When I set a page limit , say 3 in the join query result. then the query results set rows 4,5,6,7 th row has same company with different contact points.

Then user on a page duplicated on next page. How to solve this issue?
That is the first page list john, second page list peter and 3 rd page lists peter and quinn. peter is duplicated in 2 nd and 3rd page.
and the limit I set is 3 .but I get only one user, because other 2 rows are duplicated users.

What I tried is, added the main query with where IN, where in has select user id with limit set to 3.